# How to find out if a commit made it into the stable version (TensorFlow)

Tags: python, git, tensorflow, github

for this [Git issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50226) I saw that the the gitrepo updated [a file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/cd5a9ad1338b01f5fd8ce64ed86ad09bf26468ee) for TensorFlow. Now I want to check if the changes can be found in my installation.

I am using conda and installed the specific TensorFlow version in an environment. The file should be here: `tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h`

However, going down the side package route `~/anaconda3/envs/AI2.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/`, I cannot find the file.

`find | grep interpreter` in this folder tree gives me

> ./python/interpreter.py
> ./python/interpreter_wrapper
> ./python/interpreter_wrapper/**init**.py
> ./python/interpreter_wrapper/**pycache**
> ./python/interpreter_wrapper/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-36.pyc
> ./python/interpreter_wrapper/_pywrap_tensorflow_interpreter_wrapper.so
> ./python/**pycache**/interpreter.cpython-36.pyc

**Could you give me a hint where to find the file, or how to check if a specific commit made it into the stable version of TensorFlow?**
Thanks

---

**edit**: While typing, I got the answer that the version is in the nightly version, however, it would still be interesting to learn how to find out if a commit made it into a stable release. And why I cannot find the file which should be there.

Answer (score 0):

From the [git](/questions/tagged/git) side, the answer to the question is easy, *provided:*

1. that you know the commit's *hash ID;* and
2. that the answer you want is *is **this specific commit** in a repository?*

The reason for this is that Git commit hash IDs are universally unique.  If some repository has some commit, it has *that* hash ID, in that repository and in every other repository.  So you just inspect the repository to see if it has that commit, with that hash ID, and you're done.

In practice—since you've scattered this across a wide rang of tags (I plucked off the [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) one since we're not talking about Linux programming APIs here)—this answer isn't useful, not even in the [git](/questions/tagged/git) arena, because commits get *copied and modified*, and the new-and-improved—or older and worsened, or whatever—version of some commit will have a different hash ID.  You often care whether you have *some version* of some commit, rather than *some specific commit*.

For this other purpose ("do I have some version of this commit?"), you can *sometimes* use what Git calls a *patch-ID*.  To find the patch ID of some commit, run the commit through [the `git patch-ID` program](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-patch-id) (read the linked documentation for details).  Then, run potentially matching commits through `git patch-ID` as well.  If they produce the same *patch ID*, they are *equivalent commits*, even if they are technically different and therefore have different *hash* IDs.

A more general, more useful, and more portable way to find out if you have some particular feature requires effort on the part of the maintainers: changelogs, feature tests, and documentation.  If something brings new behavior, or new files, or whatever, it should be *documented*, and in some cases you might want to have, in your programming language, a way to test for the existence of this feature.  In [python](/questions/tagged/python) in particular, the core documentation has, for instance, things like [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

> `subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None,` ...
>      ...
>
> *New in version 3.5.*
> *Changed in version 3.6:* Added *encoding* and *errors* parameters
> ...

You can also use Python constructs like:

```
try:
    import what.ever
except ImportError:
    ... do whatever you need here ...
```

and similar tricks, and import `sys` and inspect `sys.version` and so on.

> The file should be here: `tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h`

The OS-specific methods for testing the existence of a file in a path depend on the OS, but when using [github](/questions/tagged/github), you can construct the URL from the file's name knowing the systematic scheme that the GitHub folks use.  For instance, [`https://github.com/git/git/blob/seen/Makefile`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/seen/Makefile) is the URL to view the version of `Makefile` at the tip commit of branch `seen` in the Git repository mirror for Git itself on GitHub.